# Overlay floating 1 step left div with another div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

I want to achieve the following on wide screens, overlay the triangle div to the div to the right (contenido) behind the div with class "evento", I've tried with position: absolute, but as bootstrap resize columns I don't get it pretty, (please look on full page):

```css
.triangulo_div{
            display: none;
        }
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.triangulo_div{
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                left: 15vh;
                top: 7.9vh;
                z-index: 5;
            }
            .triangulo_rectangulo {
                width: 0;
                height: 0;
                text-indent: -9999px;
                border-top: 90vh solid #FE6A04;
                border-right: 50px solid transparent;
            }
     }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="background-color: #001143; color: white">
    <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1 evento" style="background-color:#FE6A04;">
                BOX
            </div>
            <div id="triangulo_div" class="col-sm-2 triangulo_div"><p class="triangulo_rectangulo">triangulo rectangulo.</p></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-color:#06184A;">
                <div>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
                    totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="contenido" class="col-sm-4 contenido" style="background-color:#4FCCE8;">
                Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam
                rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 menu_siguiente" style="background-color:#06184A;">
                <div>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: .triangulo_div must be left:calc(16.66666667% * -.08) when loaded, but I want to keep it behind .evento when resizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using                 `left:-1.1em;`
instead of `left:calc(16.66666667% * -.08)`.

Looks like it was a simple thing

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea for you: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/owvyoz

The important bits in the CSS are that I've changed the positioning of the triangulo_div element from absolute to relative, and I'm calculating the left offset as a percentage

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.triangulo_div{
  display: block;
  /*position:absolute; */
  position: relative;
  /*left: 15vh; */
  left:calc(16.66666667% * 2);
  /*top: 7.9vh; */
  z-index: 5;
  }
}
```

The HTML is exactly what you have.

The 16.66666667% value comes from the width of the bootstrap .col-sm-2, so it will adapt to wider or narrower column widths as the viewport changes.

If you need to add padding or other fine-tuning it would be easy enough, eg

```
left:calc((16.66666667% * 2) + 15px);
```

I hope this helps get you unstuck!

Comment: thanks, it helps knowing the width of bootstrap column, but the problem is that with col-sm-1, the div with class name "evento" (the one I want triangulo_div behind (left:calc(16.66666667% * -.08))) gets resized too, so there are some parts of the resize where it is some pixels apart

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you want @PabloRamirez, is this closer? https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/pwozrQ

Comment: Yes it is, I already solved it, using em, I forgot about this measure